# How do I display multiple inputs?

Tags: javascript

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#user-form");
const userInput = document.querySelector("#name", "#surname", "#age", "#country");
const userList = document.querySelector(".list-group");
const firstCardBody = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[0];
const secondCardBody = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[1];
const filter = document.querySelector("#filter");
const clearButton = document.querySelector("#clear-users");
```

```html
<form id="user-form" name="form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="İsim">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Soyadı">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Yaş">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Ülke">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Bilgilerinizi Kaydedin</button>
</form>
```

My form looks like this.
But when I run my JS code, it only shows me the name not surname, age or country. How do I display all of them?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arNVd.png)

Comment: _"But when I run my JS code"_ What JS code? Please edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: You've made it very difficult to tell what in your screenshot corresponds with which part of your code (the code contains only placeholder text, your screenshot contains what I assume is user input) -- but your HTML has four input fields before the "Bilgilerinizi Kaydedin" button, and so does the form in the screenshot...

Comment: const form = document.querySelector("#user-form");
const userInput = document.querySelector("#name", "#surname", "#age", "#country");
const userList = document.querySelector(".list-group");
const firstCardBody = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[0];
const secondCardBody = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[1];
const filter = document.querySelector("#filter");
const clearButton = document.querySelector("#clear-users");
This is how my js looks like

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, it's very difficult to read. I've moved your javascript into the question itself; in future please edit the question if there are updates.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector` cannot be use the way you use it as it returns the first matched element (in your case the `name` input). To get all input fields you can do it like this:

```
const userInput = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
```

This returns all 4 input fields in an array which can be iterated via

```
userInput.forEach(input => { ... });
```

Get a specific element like this:

```
Array.from(userInput).find(input => input.id === "name");
```

Another approach would be to get the input fields via their ID's:

```
const name = document.querySelector("#name");
const surname= document.querySelector("#surname");
const age = document.querySelector("#age");
const country = document.querySelector("#country");
```

Comment: thanks that worked